# How to bind ContentType field to another field in Orchard?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I am trying to add two ImageField to my custom type so that when i select a single image it saves two version of selected file (e.g: Full Size & Thumbnail) in my fields.here i need to bind my second field to first one for accomplishing this.is there any possibilities of doing this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try jquery to complete your second form while you type in your first, or create an event on post that you can subscribe to in your save Action Method if you want to go server side only.

Comment: i want to add image field though.not a simple string or something like that.

Comment: yes that can be achieved almost the same, you use a byte[] as the type required to work with the image field.

Comment: this can also help you a lot, if you read the documentation you will be up and running in notime http://orchardimagefield.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The image field is not going to do that for you, so instead of trying to hack it, you should modify the code for the field so that it has an option to create thumbnails of your images on the fly (it should not be two separate image fields). Once you're done, you could consider contributing your work.